# p:autocomplete by group - save value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to insert autocomplete in the search engine based on for e.g. the list of subtype animals. I creted this code:

```
 <p:outputLabel value="Animals subtype:" />
 <p:autoComplete id="animals" value="#{search.animalssubtype}" completeMethod="#{zonetable.completeAnimalSubtype}" />
```

(where search.animalssubtype is value is the value from which the criterion is searched) and everything works fine. I would like to turn it into a grouping now and here is "stairs" appear. Trying to do it like this:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Animals :" />
<p:autoComplete id="animals " value="#{search.animalssubtype}" completeMethod="#{zonetable.findAllAnimal}"
                 itemLabel="#{zonetable.findAllAnimal.subtype}" itemValue="#{zonetable.findAllAnimal.subtype}" 
                groupBy="#{zonetable.findAllAnimal.type}"/>
```

It works fine, but in label I get it:

```
Animal{id=1,type=01, subtype=011 ...}
```

I tried to do it:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Animals :" />
<p:autoComplete id="animals " value="#{model.animal}" completeMethod="#{zonetable.findAllAnimal}"
                var="an" itemLabel="#{an.subtype}" itemValue="#{an.subtype}" 
                groupBy="#{an.type}"/>
```

(where model.animal is new instance object Animal [Animal animal = new Animal()]) and the label is displayed correctly, but I don`t know how to save value to "search.animalssubtype". Could you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `converter` to accomplish this, I believe.
Given your code excerpts, I can't post any working code. However, it code should look somewhat like this:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Animals :" />
<p:autoComplete id="animals"
                value="#{search.animalssubtype}"
                completeMethod="#{zonetable.findAllAnimal}"
                converter="#{animalConverter}
                itemLabel="#{animalssubtype.name}"
                itemValue="#{animalssubtype}"/>
```

And this is an example of a converter:

```
@Named("animalConverter")
@RequestScoped
public class AnimalConverter implements Converter {

  @Inject
  private Service service;

  @Inject
  private Search search;

  @Override
  public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String s) {

    try {
      Long id = NumberUtils.createLong(s);
      if(id == null) {
        return search.getAnimal();
      }
      return service.find(id);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      // ignore!
      return search.getAnimal();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object o) {
    String result = "";
    if (o != null && o instanceof Animal) {
      Animal animal = (Animal) o;
      result = String.valueOf(animal.getId());
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```